# Stored search procedure in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I have a table in an Oracle 12c databse called testimonial that has content as a column. I have created a stored search procedure to find testimonials whose content matches an input string that is defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Search_Testimonials
    (keyword IN VARCHAR2,
     output OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS
    BEGIN OPEN output
    FOR SELECT *
    FROM Testimonial T
    WHERE T.content LIKE keyword;
    END;
    /

VAR output REFCURSOR;
    DECLARE
    keyword VARCHAR2(15) := '%like%';
    BEGIN
    Search_Testimonials(keyword, :output);
    END;
    /
```

I am trying to run a test on this procedure using the input 'like'. From what I have found on this site and other sites I should run the following:

```
var output refcursor;
exec Search_Testimonials('like', output);
print output;
```

However my output is just:

```
OUTPUT
------
```

When it should display all the records in testimonial table as they all contain the word 'like.'

Am I messing up something in the procedure? I've looked around and this seems to be how to do it as far as I can figure. Thanks!

Comment: In one of the two calls, you are passing in a keyword that has wild cards at the beginning and at the end of the string.  In the other you are not.  If you aren't using wildcards, your query will only return rows where `t.content = 'like'`.  Using the `like` operator without using wildcards in your string generally doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hmmm okay I think I understand. So how do I modify the first search to add wildcards in front of and after the keyword that I am searching for?

Comment: The first search has the wildcards.  The second one doesn't.  If you always intend to do a `like` search with leading and trailing wildcards (note that this is very expensive as data volumes grow because it cannot be indexed), I'd add the wildcards in your search function rather than forcing the caller to add them.

Comment: I think I'm more confused now, I thought the second block was just to set the output refcursor value

Comment: Your first block (the anonymous PL/SQL block) is passing in the literal string '%like%' as the first parameter.  Your second block (the `EXEC`) is passing in the literal string 'like'.  You're passing in two very different search strings so you would expect to get two very different results.

Comment: Oh, okay, I understand now. My first block is the query and the second block is what I use to test the query with the term '%like%'.

Comment: Your post has three distinct blocks of code.  The first `create or replace procedure ...` creates the procedure.  The second `declare keyword ...` is one method of calling the procedure.  The third `exec search_testimonials` is a second method of calling the procedure.  The two methods you have posted for calling the procedure are passing in different input parameters.  That will cause them to return very different results.

Comment: What is the DDL statement for your `Testimonial` table? Are you aware of case sensitivity? Did you test the `SELECT` statement of your procedure manually?